# Springboot server can't get a cookie domain, it get cookie object though

Tags: java, spring, cookies, request

In Java 17, Springboot 2.x.

I'm using 2 servers that one is `simba.com` and another is using `cute.simba.com` what is subdomain.

I'm developing a method what can delete `simba.com` cookie and `cute.simba.com` cookie.

However, i can catch both cookies in the controller but i can't get domain of them. It just seems 'null' value.

I don't understand why those cookies don't contain domains, i created its with domain though.

**This is source what get cookies in the Controller.**

```
    public static void deleteCookie(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if (cookies != null) {
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                cookie.setValue(null);
                cookie.setMaxAge(0);
                response.addCookie(cookie);
            }
        }
     }
```

**Created cookie with domain.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aW2jX.png)

**Debugging to values of Cookie**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C3b7.png)